# AES encryption with pycrypto

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have a code snippet on javascript that I'm trying to convert to python

```
var cipherAlgorithm = 'aes256';
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(cipherAlgorithm, cipher);
password = decipher.update(encryptedpass, 'hex', 'utf8')+ decipher.final('utf8');
```

I'm trying to rewrite that in python using pythoncrypto and I'm just getting the wrong values no matter what I do

```
cyphertext=faaafaaa"
cipher=AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, "\0"*16)
cipher.decrypt(cypertext)
```

and it returns the wrong value.  (didn't decrypt correctly)
in the javascript code (I'm not a js expert ) I noticed that the output encoding is utf8
so I tries something like this

```
unicode(cipher.decrypt(cyphertext), "utf-8")
```

but I'm getting an error
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 6: invalid start byte

what's the solution?